# How I insert a time-date-stamp in MongoDB with a Golang Sruct?

Tags: mongodb, go, timestamp, datestamp

I have the following struct:

type TypeIncidence struct {
Number      int    `bson:"number" json:"number"`
Description string `bson:"description" json:"description"`
Date_time_stamp string `bson:"dateTimeStamp" json:"date_time_stamp"`
}

and I want insert a document in a collection:

```
type TypeIncidence struct {
    Number      int    `bson:"number" json:"number"`
    Description string `bson:"description" json:"description"`
    Date_time_stamp **string?**
}


var incidence TypeIncidence

incidence.Number = 1
Description =" Text"
Date_time_stamp = **string?**
```

What data type would I have to use in a Golang structure to store date_time_struct a string?

If I want to store with the following format **'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'**, what module and/or function should I use in golang? (in local machine or server converting zone time)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `time.Time`:

```
CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at"`
```

However, I would recommend that you store [Epoch Unix timestamp](https://www.epochconverter.com/) (the number of seconds since Jan 1st 1970) because it is universal:

```
CreatedAt int64 `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at"`
```

I have tried in the past to store `time.Time` in MongoDB through Golang but then I had trouble when I parsed the same information into a `datetime` object in Python. If you would like to be compatible across languages and technologies, storing the Epoch Unix timestamp would be a great option.

Comment: good point on storing it as integer for the case that multiple languages are gonna work with the same database collection